# what happens when we insert some character in a string?

Tags: c++

i am learning string class and want to know that when i inserts a dollar sign or comma at a specific location in a string as in example what actually happens to the digit which is already placed at that location? Does the .insert() function overwrite on the digit already placed at that loaction or first shifts it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void dollarFormat(string &);

int main ()
{
string input;

Get the dollar amount from the user.
cout << "Enter a dollar amount in the form nnnnn.nn : ";
cin >> input;
dollarFormat(input);
cout << "Here is the amount formatted:\n";
cout << input << endl;
return 0;
}

void dollarFormat(string &currency)
{
  int dp;

  dp = currency.find('.'); // Find decimal point
  if (dp > 3) // Insert commas
  {
    for (int x = dp - 3; x > 0; x -= 3)
    currency.insert(x, ",");
  }
  currency.insert(0, "$"); // Insert dollar sign
}

Program Output with Example Input Shown in Bold
Enter a dollar amount in the form nnnnn.nn: 1084567.89 [Enter]
Here is the amount formatted:
$1,084,567.89
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a character into a string, all the characters to the right of the insertion point get shifted to the right, then the character overwrites the existing character at the insertion point.  The string may need to be reallocated to accommodate for the extra character.

Overwriting then shifting doesn't hold up (try drawing it out).

Comment: See [std::string::insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert).